# python password generator input validation kinda working

Tags: python

I have a while loop with a try-except block to prompt the user to use letters, numbers and special characters. The validation works if the user does not enter 'y' or 'n', my problem is when the user enters something other than 'y' or 'n', the code start back at the beginning with letters again. How can I continue to validate input and not go back to the beginning if input is invalid?

```
# Prompt user for whether to include letters, numbers and special characters
while True:
    try:
        include_letters = input("Include letters? (y/n): ").lower()
        if include_letters not in ('y', 'n'):
            raise ValueError("Invalid input. Enter 'y' or 'n'")
        include_letters = include_letters == 'y'


        include_numbers = input("Include numbers? (y/n): ").lower()
        if include_numbers not in ('y', 'n'):
            raise ValueError("Invalid input. Enter 'y' or 'n'")
        include_numbers = include_numbers == 'y'


        include_special_chars = input("Include special characters? (y/n): ").lower()
        if include_special_chars not in ('y', 'n'):
            raise ValueError("Invalid input. Enter 'y' or 'n'")
        include_special_chars = include_special_chars == 'y'


        if not (include_letters or include_numbers or include_special_chars):
            raise ValueError("You must select at least one of letters, numbers or special characters to continue.")

        break
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
```

Here is my issue

```
Include letters? (y/n): y
Include numbers? (y/n): y
Include special characters? (y/n): g
Invalid input. Enter 'y' or 'n'
Include letters? (y/n): y
Include numbers? (y/n): k
Invalid input. Enter 'y' or 'n'
Include letters? (y/n):
```

Comment: You currently require your user to answer three questions correctly, and if any one fails, they have to start over again, because you use *one* loop. Instead, use a separate loop for *each* input, so that once "include letters" has been satisfactorily answers, a failure to answer "include numbers" correctly only results in *that* question repeating.

Comment: ... or create a function for "y"/"n" selection with a loop inside and call it multiple times.